# How to get volatility of a stock price using Artificial Neural Networks?

Tags: neural-networks, volatility-forecasting

I am working on how to get the volatility using ANNs. I don't know how to go about it after getting the output of a single neuron.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, volatility has nothing to do with ANN. Volatility is either StDev of your resource price (or returns) or comparison with more global market index (think of S&P 500)